# Quick question about XPath/DOM

Tags: dom, xpath

How can I get the text in an element excluding contained tags?
Example:

```
<div>Blah blah blah <span>exclude this</span></div>
```

I want to get

> Blah blah blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text node that is a child of the div element.

```
/div/text()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to weed out a bunch of new line characters, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It might be appropriate to use `normalize-space(/div/text())` to take care of line feeds, but it will also trim leading/trailing whitespace and collapse any repeated whitespace characters, which you may/may not want.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use that? I'm using `//form[@name='delform']/text()` now. EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out. `//form[@name='delform']/text()[normalize-space()]`

Comment: Be aware that /div/text() returns all the text node children, but normalize-space(/div/text()) in XPath 1.0 selects only the first, and in XPath 2.0 throws an error if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

To get any inner text inside `div` you need `/div//text()`, otherwise you will be able to get only child texts of `div`.